# Unable to display proper format in email using transport builder in magento2

Tags: magento2, email-templates, send-mail

I am trying to display string as `<p>Hello, Welcome</p>\n` in my local mail. But it is display with given html tag instead of only string.

Let me know how it can be solve or what can be its solution.

```
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
            $emailTemplateVariables = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

                $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->_template)
                ->setTemplateOptions(array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $store))
                ->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
                ->setFrom(['name' => ' Admin','email' => 'admin@support.net'])
                ->addTo($to,"Admin");
```

Comment: add code of email_templates.xml in question

Comment: i have added template in admin Marketing > Email Template